# virtualbox no shared folder access

Tags: virtualbox

I am running a host machine with windows 7 on it and installed virtual box on it several months ago. All of a sudden I am no longer able to access the shared folder I have been using. I can open a terminal and type **cd /media/shared/networks** and I get the error message **bash: cd: /media/shared/networks: no such file or directory**. There is a folder named shared on my windows desktop and there is a folder named networks within that shared folder. I am not sure where the issue is. If I type **cd /media/shared** the **pwd** returns as **/media/shared**, but when I **ls** nothing is returned, it shows that the folder is empty. has anyone else run into this type of problem and if so how did you fix it?

Comment: I think this question is a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify in /media/sf_networks

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_auto

resume:

> With Linux guests, auto-mounted shared folders are mounted into the
>   /media directory, along with the prefix sf_. For example, the shared
>   folder myfiles would be mounted to /media/sf_myfiles